# Passing segue data through a Google AdMob interstitial delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, admob, segue, interstitial

I have an app that has four buttons that all pass data to a modal view controller. This is accomplished by assigning tags to the 4 buttons, and adding some conditionals inside prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "modalSegue" {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ModalViewController
        if sender?.tag == 1 {
            secondViewController.title = "Lawn Mowing"
        }
        else if sender?.tag == 2 {
            secondViewController.title = "Landscaping"
        }
        else if sender?.tag == 3 {
            secondViewController.title = "Hardscaping"
        }
        else if sender?.tag == 4 {
            secondViewController.title = "Tree Removal"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my button:

```
@IBAction func servicesButton(sender: UIButton) {
    adCounter += 1
    if adCounter == 4 {
        adCounter = 0
        if (interstitial.isReady) {
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            interstitial = createAd()
        }
        else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("modalSegue", sender: sender)
        }
    }
    else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("modalSegue", sender: sender)
    }
}
```

Works perfect.

**The problem comes when I introduce AdMob Interstitials**

Every 4th button tap (on servicesButton), I call an Interstitial. When the interstitial is closed (via interstitialDidDismissScreen), I perform the segue to the modal view controller:

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("modalSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

**But no data gets passed!! :(**
The modal just loads up without the secondViewController title. I believe it is because there is no sender, which gives the button tags and passes the data... Correct? I also tried sender: self in the interstitial delegate method, but that did not do anything.

How can I continue to pass this information to the modal view controller *after* the user dismisses the interstitial? Or is there an overall better way to handle this?  i NEED the interstitial to load up BEFORE the segue, as there will be much less of a chance of accidental taps.

Thanks. If you need further clarification or questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to clear your count in your IBAction when you present the interstitial, and then when the interstitial is dismissed you can call your servicesButton function with the button that was pressed as the sender if you have IBOutlets for them.

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    self.servicesButton(buttonThatWasPressed) 
}
```

This will then recall all your logic.

Another way would be to set a class-level variable for the new views title and set that when the button is pressed, then no matter where you call presentSegue from, in prepareForSegue you will still have access to what the new title will be.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance here. I'm a little stuck on buttonThatWasPressed. How can I pass this information to the interstitialDidDismissScreen method?

Comment: If you have your buttons in code or as an IBOutlet then that would be the button that you passed as the sender argument

Comment: One thing I did not mention in my original post above: I have all 4 buttons linked to the same touchUpInside event (servicesButton). I did this in storyboard. I then just set a tag for each. I thought this would be a little cleaner code, since all 4 buttons call the same logic.

Comment: Okay then you would need to take my second approach and set the new title when you press the button to a class variable that you could check in prepareForSegue

Comment: I'm actually getting pretty close with your first suggestion! :) I added an IBOutlet and have it as the sender: self.servicesButton(lawnmowingOutlet) - but how do I handle the other 3? a Switch statement?

Comment: You would have to create an outlet for each button that could display the interstitial in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122342/discussion-between-joe-and-pbush25).

Comment: Your second solution did the trick here. I was spinning my tires way too much trying to work out the first solution. Gotta love the static keyword! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!